# IBM Message Broker Java API: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.mq.MQException

Tags: java, ibm-integration-bus

I am trying to connect to a broker in Message Broker using ibm's java API: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmbhelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.etools.mft.doc%2Fbe43410_.htm

I am trying to use the example provided at that link (I am using a broker,port and queue manager that I KNOW exists) and I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.mq.MQException
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:72)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:134)
    at com.ibm.broker.config.proxy.MQBrokerConnectionParameters.getSender(MQBrokerConnectionParameters.java:565)
    at com.ibm.broker.config.proxy.BrokerProxy.<init>(BrokerProxy.java:289)
    at com.ibm.broker.config.proxy.BrokerProxy.getInstance(BrokerProxy.java:777)
    at BarAdmin.connectToBroker(BarAdmin.java:197)
    at BarAdmin.main(BarAdmin.java:52)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're missing the JAR that contains `com.ibm.mq.MQException` at runtime or the version of the JAR you do have doesn't contain that class.

Find the JAR that contains that class and add it to your runtime CLASSPATH.

Comment: Thanks! - any ideas where I might be able to find the jar file that contains this???

Comment: I found it, but now I need `javax.resource.spi.ResourceAdapterInternalException` ... I feel like I'm missing a whole set of jar file or something... It would be nice if IBM told me what I needed in that documentation...

Comment: Keep adding JARs until all the dependencies are satisfied and the exceptions go away.

Comment: I would... if I could infind a jar with the javax.resource.spi.ResourceAdapterInternalException class :-/

Comment: This should help:http://www.findjar.com/index.x?query=+javax.resource.spi.ResourceAdapterInternalException

Comment: It's `connector.jar` or something similar. (Sorry if it is late now.)

Answer (score 0):

The MQ install directory contains a directory called java/lib that contains all the jars you need.